# How can a Rogue gets attacks in another player or monsters turn?

Tags: dnd-4e, rogue, sneak-attack

How can a `Rogue` gets attacks in another player or monsters turn?

The `Sneak Attack` feature of the `Rogue` can happen `Once per turn`[[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=6)]

> SNEAK ATTACK
>   When you make an attack with a light blade, a hand crossbow, a shortbow, or a sling and hit an enemy granting combat advantage to you, that enemy takes extra damage based on your level (see the Sneak Attack table). You can deal this extra damage only once per turn.

Apart from an `Opportunity Attack`, is there any other way for a `Rogue` to get an attack in another turn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 3 primary ways to get attacks during another player or monters's turn:

- Immediate actions -  several rogue powers grant immediate interrupts or reactions, one of the primary ones is `riposte strike`. if the rogue has CA then Sneak attack applies
- Opportunity attacks - while most rogues aren't great in melee if they can hit with an opportunity attack and have CA then they can deal their sneak attack damage.
- Granted attacks - Several leader classes specialize in granting attacks, if they can give their attacks to the rogue while she has CA then she can apply her sneak attack.

Let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: Oh, there are some delicious delicious riposte builds, like my Don Bugbear De la Mancha, and various helf abuse of it. See also agile opportunist.

Answer (score 1):

Any time a `Rogue` would attack as the last Standard action of his turn, instead of attacking, use the Standard action to ready the attack, the trigger being "as soon as it's another turn". Then the attack takes place off the Rogue's turn. Note that this is a special case of "immediate actions" that wax eagle mentioned.

Comment: While technically correct, this isn't especially helpful, since the asker's goal is almost certainly to get the Sneak Attack bonus damage more than once per round.

Comment: Could they action point a held standard for the above situation?  Then they would get the sneak attack twice in a round.  Not sure if that's allowed, though.

Comment: @Lechlerfan yes, but it's probably more efficient to just take the action point sneak attack feat...